# Spring Security, authorize access, denied for specific URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am wondering if its possible to give access to specific URL to all users?
I have a rest controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/travel/")
public class TravelController {

@RequestMapping(value = { "/" }, method = { RequestMethod.POST })
public String newTravel(HttpEntity<String> httpEntity)
{
...
return null;
}

@RequestMapping(value = { "/follow/{travelId}/{email}/" }, method = { RequestMethod.POST })
public ResponseEntity<String> followTravel(@PathVariable int travelId,@PathVariable String email, HttpEntity<String> httpEntity)
{
...
}
```

I would like to restrict access to all POST to authenticated users, but authorize `followTravel()` to all users.

my security config is :

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.csrf() //
                .disable() //
                .authorizeRequests() //
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/travel/follow/**") // permit all POST to authenticated
                .anonymous() //
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**") // permit all POST to authenticated
                .authenticated() //
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/**") // permit all PUT to authenticated
                .authenticated() //
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/**") // permit all DELETE to authenticated
                .authenticated() //
                .anyRequest() //
                .permitAll() //
                .and() //
                .httpBasic() //
                .and() //
                .sessionManagement() //
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED);
        // .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
```

I tried settings

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/travel/follow/**") // permit all POST to authenticated
    .anonymous() //
```

before or after

```
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**") // permit all POST to authenticated
                .authenticated() //
```

but no success.  I usually find answers in SO, but didn't for this one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, configuration was correct, but security was not correctly defined, there was 2 classes extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and the one i modified was never read.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, YOUR_FINAL_STATIC_STRING_URL).permitAll();
```

Comment: my bad, i was connected when i tried it. so it is working when connected but not when anonymous.